# Cannot auto add group in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.6 and have a CustomUser.
I want all users that are created to be added to a group by default.

I have tried to add it to the save method for my user but its not working.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True)
    ...
    objects = MyUserManager()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='myhistory')
    self.groups.add(group)
    self.section="testing it saves"
    super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It does call the save method as it sets the section as above - but wont set the group.
It finds the group fine - just no setting it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: why you call super from SCVUser, not MyUser?

Comment: typo! fixed now. Its supposed to be MyUser.

Comment: Have only one idea: try to call super before adding group

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed indentation,

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True)
    ...
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        group = Group.objects.get(name='myhistory')
        self.groups.add(group)
        self.section="testing it saves"
        super(SCVUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, I missed it in my example - sorry. trying to simplify the situation.